# Elementor Social Icons Widget - hide if no url

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am using the Social Icons Widget within Elementor. The urls come from Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) attached the the post.

If one of the urls is empty though, I do not want the icon to show.

I have been trying use the hook 'elementor/widget/render_content' but not sure what do do with it once I have the element.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for others that wants a solution for this. You may use Elementor's Custom Code and insert a javascript code that will remove the empty links once the page has loaded.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.elementor-social-icon').each(function(i,e){
            if(jQuery(this).attr('href') === undefined || 
             jQuery(this).attr('href') == ""){
                jQuery(this).parent().remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

This code checks for all the social icons with a class of `elementor-social-icon` then removes the span container that contains the anchor tag if the `href` attribute is undefined or blank